# Using a local folder how to store google markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

1. var newIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/red-pushpin.png');
2. var newIcon = 'http://images/red-pushpin.png';
3. var newIcon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png';

   var MarkerOption = {map:map, position:MarkerLatLng, title:name, icon:newIcon };
   var Marker = new google.maps.Marker(MarkerOption);

I am using a VB WebBrowser Control to load an HTML page & access Google Maps via
javascript. It all works, except that I can only access the markers by line 3 above
but I want to use a local image folder (images) but javascrip cant 'see' it, yet 
it is in the same directory as the HTML page.
What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MarkerOptions docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions), the icon should be a URL.

So you will only be able to access an image within a url and local files embedded with **file:///** tend to be ignored by browsers if the website is being served over **http**.
So only your 3 line is working.

If in case you want to access your icon image from the local drive, you can do it like this:

`var newIcon= "http://mysite.com/images/red-pushpin.png"`

> In place of mysite replace it with the url that you get for your website when you run it

Comment: I am only on a home PC so no server. Anyway, since posting this I have discovered that google.maps.MarkerImage will accept a path but only an absolute one, ie 'c:\users\fred\images\red-pushpin.png' works. As this is run from VB via a WebBrowser I can pass the path (My.Computer.Info.DirectoryPath) to javascript and then Line 1 above becomes var newIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(path + '\images\red-pushpin.png');